# Finding Where Alias Points Even With Deleted File

Tags: macos, alias

Can I find where an alias was pointing to, if the file is deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the finder : <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or right-click (<kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> + click) → *Get Info*

The path (location) will be identified by the *Original* field.